# capturar mas de 1 valor con ajax y laravel 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo en mi vista dos select con datos, los cuales quiero capturar sus values. Puedo hacerlo con un select y el metodo `$.get`, pero no sé como hacerlo para que me capture dos datos y llevarlo a un controlador.

No sé si se entiende mi problema, pero dejo lo que tengo para capturar un solo dato.

Ruta:

```
Route::get('imp/{id}', 'VentasController@getIva');
```

Controlador:

```
public function getIva(Request $request, $id)
{

    //$test = M_DCVT::where('id' , '=' , $id)->select('mimpcd_id')->first();
    //$test = $test->mimpcd_id;


    if($request->ajax()){

        //$imp = M_IMPT::Iva($id, foo);
        //return response()->json($imp->mimpts);


    }   

}
```

Script:

```
$("#mdccod_id").change(function(event){

    var select = $('#msocod_id option:selected').val(); 

    $.get("/imp/"+event.target.value+"",function(response){          
      $("#hidden").val(response)
    });
});
```

Comment: No estoy seguro de entender, quieres enviar dos valores con ajax a un solo controlador/ruta en laravel al momento de hacer clic en un botón o cuando cambia cualquiera de los dos select? es más fácil si pones el código acá (en la pregunta) y no en imágenes.

Comment: Claro, son dos selects que tengo. Por el momento solo puedo capturar uno el del evento change de jquery, entonces no se si me falta poner algo en la ruta o el controlador.
Por el momento tengo asi el controlador:
public function getIva(Request $request, $id)
 {
  
  //$test = M_DCVT::where('id' , '=' , $id)->select('mimpcd_id')->first();
  //$test = $test->mimpcd_id;

      
  if($request->ajax()){
   
   //$imp = M_IMPT::Iva($id, foo);
   //return response()->json($imp->mimpts);
   
   
  } 
  
 }

Comment: Agrega el código a la pregunta (editándola), por favor.

Comment: Los dos valores se capturarían con el mismo evento: `$("#mdccod_id").change()` ?

Comment: Edite la pregunta y agregue el codigo.
Claro, tendria que capturar el valor del select $(#mdccod_id) y del $(#msocod_id)

Comment: Mi pregunta no es qué tiene que capturar, es con qué evento o eventos se deben capturar, solo con el change de uno de los dos select? (tal y como está actualmente).

Comment: Claro como lo tengo sería solo con el change de un select. Ahora si se puede hacer de otra forma sería genial, solo que ésta forma se me ocurre ya que tambien soy novato en jquery jeje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo entonces que tenemos dos select:

```
<select id="mdccod_id">
  <option value="1">valor1</option>
  <option value="2">valor2</option>
</select>

<select id="msocod_id">
  <option value="1">valor1</option>
  <option value="2">valor2</option>
</select>
```

Y que vamos a capturar el evento de cambio (según lo que respondes en los comentarios) en solo uno de los dos select, para lo cual vamos a mantener el get que se está utilizando:

```
$("#mdccod_id").change(function(event){

  var select = $('#mdccod_id option:selected').val(); 
  var select2 = $('#msocod_id option:selected').val(); 

  $.get("/imp/" + select + "/" + select2 ,function(response){          
    $("#hidden").val(response)
  });
});
```

La anterior es una solución bastante "manual" la cuál se podría mejorar dependiendo de como tengas proyectada la aplicación y también ponerle algún valor por defecto en caso que no haya nada en los valores que toma de los select.

A continuación modificamos la ruta en Laravel para que pueda recibir los dos parámetros, los cuales haremos obligatorios:

```
Route::get('imp/{id}/{valor2}', 'VentasController@getIva');
```

Por último, simplemente agregamos el parámetro adicional al método del controlador:

```
public function getIva(Request $request, $id, $valor2)
{

    if($request->ajax()){
        // hacer lo que quieras con $id
        // hacer lo que quieras con $valor2
    }   

}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @Shaz, lo voy a probar y te cuento como me fue. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Shaz, ahora funcionó todo bien.
Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.